# Adding -1,0, or 1 randomly to a number in C

Tags: c, random, numbers, range, generator

I am trying to figure out a way that I can randomly generate -1,0, or 1 using srand and rand. Whenever I do, however, I am only able to get the values inside the range generated and never the -1 or 1.

This is what I tried:

```
   int value;
   srand(time(NULL));
   value=2*rand()/(RAND_MAX)-1;
```

However, when executed, I always generate 0. I want to be able to generate -1 and 1 occasionally. The problem is I have to use the rand and srand, as part of the specifications. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance :).

Comment: Remember to call `srand(time(NULL));` no more than once in your program. Especially do not put it inside a loop or in a function that gets called more than once.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
value = (rand() % 3) - 1;
```

The expression `rand() % 3` generates a random number between `0` and `2` (inclusive), then subtract one to get between `-1` and `1` (inclusive).

Comment: Thank you for helping this noob :)! I truly appreciate it.

Comment: There is a very slight bias with this approach when `RAND_MAX % 3` is not 2. When this is a problem, the fix is usually to discard when they happen the last one or two problematic values that `rand()` can take.

Comment: `2^n-1 mod 3` is never 2, so for many common values of `RAND_MAX` there will be bias.

Answer (score 2):

First, you want 3 different values but you're only asking for 2. Second, in some implementations (and apparently the one you're using) RAND_MAX == INT_MAX so your calculation is subject to overflow. You can address that by using floating point

```
// srand(time(NULL)); Only do this once per invocation of your program
int value = (int)(3.0*rand()/RAND_MAX) - 1;
```

or long long

```
int value = 3LL*rand()/RAND_MAX - 1;
```

or by moving the factor into the divisor:

```
int value = rand()/(RAND_MAX/3) - 1;
```

Edit: note that these will produce slightly skewed (more or less as RAND_MAX is less or more) results because RAND_MAX isn't a multiple of 3. You can avoid this with:

```
int r;
do
{
    r = rand();
} while (r >= RAND_MAX/3 * 3);
int value = r / (RAND_MAX/3) - 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! For some reason, all three of your suggestions are resulting in -1 each time. I am not sure why that is as your reasoning makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: @user2129657 They work here ... what values is rand() returning, and what is RAND_MAX? Possibly your implementation doesn't define RAND_MAX correctly.

Comment: @JimBalter, +1 for attempting to evenly distribute the results and showing how.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an off-by-one error and potentially suffers from integer overflow.

Change

```
value = 2 * rand() / RAND_MAX - 1;
```

to

```
value = rand() / (RAND_MAX / 3 + 1) - 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried the second expression but it generates 1 every time.

Comment: @pmg: Good point, I've removed that remark.